# Bug in NHibernate Aliasing

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, formula

I am using NHibernate for my database management.
In one class I am calculating a property using this formula:

```
(SELECT MIN(x.timestamp) FROM (SELECT MAX(r.Timestamp) AS timestamp, r.Meter_Id FROM Reading r, Meter m WHERE r.Meter_Id = m.Id AND m.Store_Id = Id GROUP BY r.Meter_Id) AS x)
```

The generated query looks like this:

```
(SELECT MIN(x.timestamp) FROM (SELECT MAX(r.Timestamp) AS timestamp, r.Meter_Id FROM Reading r, Meter m WHERE r.Meter_Id = m.Id AND m.Store_Id = this_.Id GROUP BY r.Meter_Id) AS this_.x)
```

Obviously the name in the AS statement is renamed to this_.x, which causes the error.

It seems to be a known bug: [NHibernate JIRA #NH-2878](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2878)

Does enyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but I don't actually see why you need the alias in that particular formula.

In a more general sense, you have a few options:

- **Work around the issue.** You could use a stored procedure, or load more data and do the calculation in-memory.
- **Fix it.** NHibernate is open source -- pull down the code, find the cause, isolate it in a test, fix it, and send a pull request.
- **Get someone else to fix it.** If your company is using NHibernate and this is important to them, they could probably sponsor another NHibernate contributor to implement a fix.

Comment: The alias is definitely needed, as a SQL error occures when it is not used. I would like to know if anyone already got a fix for this. If there is none, I think I ll use a database view for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when calling a database function from within a Fluent NHibernate Map.Formula() method. My workaround was to repeat the full function name instead of trying to use an ailas.

For example, where EntityColumn2 is a column that is already being referenced\loaded into the entity.

```
SELECT My_Db_Function.Column1
FROM My_Db_Function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...) 
WHERE My_Db_Function.Column2 = EntityColumn2
```

The result is that the **My_Db_Function** references stay as is (and are not aliased by NHibernate) and the EntityColumn2 is correctly aliased by NHibernate.

Comment: Prefixing names can even work for types. In my case NHibernate prefixed the type `datetime` with the table alias as well, but after changing it to `sys.datetime` it worked. Also mentioned in http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate: "NHibernate will automatically pre-pend the alias of the current entity table to anything that looks like a unqualified column access"

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know how to fix the bug but you could try writing your calculation as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(r.Timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM Reading r, Meter m
WHERE r.Meter_Id = m.Id AND m.Store_Id = Id
GROUP BY r.Meter_Id
order by Max(r.timestamp) asc
```